# Is there a way to invert a complex matrix in dlib?

Tags: c++, dlib

Is there a way to invert a complex matrix `dlib::matrix<std::complex<float> >` in dlib? `dlib::inv()` does not seem to accept complex input. Or am I doing something wrong?

Example:

```
dlib::matrix<std::complex<float> > M(dlib::identity_matrix<std::complex<float> >(2));
dlib::matrix<std::complex<float> > Minv = dlib::inv(M);
```

The first line compiles, the second results in a compilation error:

```
.../dlib/matrix/matrix_lu.h:41:9: error: static assertion failed: Failed assertion
    COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT((is_same_type<float, type>::value ||
```

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: @idclev463035818, Edited. Is this what you are asking for?